# Tree Panel node label break in extjs4

Tags: extjs

this is a node in the tree

```
{
  text:'more then a_veryverylongword ',
  leaf: true
}
```

Here the problem is that a very very long word is not shown but if I resize the panel the word is shown?

Does someone tell me, what i should do to break the word? the css is not working to modify the size of the panel is not an option.

Thanks

Comment: can you post the code or part of code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample edited code from sencha and its working...

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            { text: "detention", leaf: true },
            { text: "homework", expanded: true, children: [
                { text: "book report", leaf: true },
                { text: 'more then a_veryverylongword ', leaf: true}
            ] },
            { text: "buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 250,
    height: 150,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```